# Defining ( Column Type ) for Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm Designing a database using MySQL , Right now am in the phase of documenting in which I have to Define every Column's data type .
when it comes to each table on its own , there's no problem , but I have problem with 1-m Relationships , because I don't know how to Define the Foreign key's Data type ( because in its original table its type is "SERIAL" - coz its Primary Key ) But I can't Define it as SERIAL when it's FK . Can You Help Me ?

EX :
PUBLISHERS [ **Publisher_ID ( SERIAL )** | Publisher_Name ( Varchar(50) ) | .. etc]

Books [ **Book_ID (SERIAL)** | **Publisher_ID (?)** | Book_Price ( Decimal (5,2) ) | .. etc ]

thanks

Comment: You can also define publisher_id as int ?

Comment: I want it to be Generated Automatically for each Publisher added to the database .
in case of defining it as INT , I Give the user the ability to add a unique number by himself . :)

Comment: no user cant enter unique number by himself because if you set it autoincrement and primary key. its automatically add id autoincrement.

Comment: see in answer @petern give the same answer , using table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SERIAL` in MySql is just an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`. Therefore use 
`BIGINT UNSIGNED` when defining FK column, like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE publishers(
publisher_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
publisher_name VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(publisher_id)
);

CREATE TABLE books(
book_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
publisher_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
title VARCHAR(100),
book_price DECIMAL(5,2),
PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publishers (publisher_id)
);
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae01e/1)**